# Audio playback on mobile phone

Tags: mobile, html5-audio, flashlite

I have a problem with deciding about Flash lite vs html5 audio tag for streaming music on mobile devices.

If it's flash lite, then any steps how to get it working would be great, no actual code needed, because I tried but it didn't play. i don't realy know as2, because I usually use as3.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into a framework like JPlayer (http://jplayer.org/)?  That will use HTML5 audio if available and otherwise fallback to Flash.